# Appengine Cold start on every request call (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine

I've recently started having coldstarts on nearly every call to my appengine app.  Initially I thought this was an issue with Cloud Endpoints, however now I believe it is an appengine issue, or something else in my code.
This started on my most recent deployment.  I'm at a loss right now as to what is going on.  It has made my app useless.  I have tried 1.7.4 and 1.7.5 and both have this problem.

The requests work other than being extremely slow!  Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I can not continue with 10-15 request times!

Update:  By looking at my running instances I see NO instances running even after making a request.  Previously instances would remain running after requests were made.  It appears when a request is made an instance is spun up, serves the request, and then dies.  There are no errors in my logs.  No changes have been made to my app settings or billing.  This app does have billing enabled.

Update 2:  I have adjusted my idle instance settings(which up to this point have worked and have been left untouched).  I set to a min of 1 and max of 2.  The instances are staying alive and serving requests as normal.  Previously it was set to automatic-1. Not sure what is going on here, perhaps Google adjusting the request scheduler or something.  Not COOL!

Comment: Is this just API calls or all requests to your application?

Comment: After further testing this seems to be all requests.  It is not always consistent so it has been difficult to determine what is going on.  Right now it is continuing to have cold starts on nearly every request, making my app useless.  Perhaps an appengine issue...I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Not sure if it's related if you're still seeing issues, but there was a ops issue with appengine recently (the 21st) which would produce exactly the symptoms you're seeing. https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/R39uBoTCJqI

Comment: @JesseRusak that does sound like my issue.  Still don't know what is going on.  Going to leave my settings changed for the time being

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an open issue on code.google.com.  Apparently this is a real appengine issue that is effecting some, if not all apps at the moment.  I do not have a solution at this time other than setting the idle minimum instances to 1 (or greater).  Even doing this, the new dynamic instances that are spun up die almost immediately after serving a request.  Just waiting on a fix from google at this point.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8844

Comment: looks like the issue is removed :( but one of my app is exhibiting the same problem

Comment: interesting.  perhaps fixed in the upcoming appengine release

Comment: But if they fixed it, they should mark it as resolved and not delete the issue itself.